# FIN pkt with HTTP connection after some time

Tags: apache, http, networking, tcp, client-server

Opened 2 TCP connections :
1. Normal connection(while implementing echo server,client) & 
2. HTTP connection

Opened HTTP connection with curl(modified) utility while running apache as server, where curl is not sending GET request for some time after connection establishment.
For normal connection after connection establishment, server is waiting for request from client.
But as observed, Strangely in HTTP connection after connection establishment, if GET request is not coming from client(for some time), server is sending FIN pkt to client & closing his part of connection.
*Is it a mandatory condition for HTTP client to send GET request immediately after initial connection.*

Comment: Let's clarify this. You have a web server listening to the port 80. When you establish a TCP connection between web server and echo client, the connection doesn't drop (no FIN sent by server) BUT if you establish connection between a modified curl and the server, without pushing any data, the server drops the connection?

Comment: Yes except didn't tried this condition "connection between web server and echo client". But tried simple connection(without port 80) echo client, echo server and in another case TCP connection between web server(port 80) and  a modified curl. And observed as Web server is sending FIN after some time(within 1sec), which is not the case with echo client, server. So just wants to confirm that is this magic happens because of HTTP(port 80).
Sorry if my Que is not properly explained, which initially seems proper to me.

Comment: then WHY my answer is not enough? echo server got no timeouts, apache server (not the PROTOCOL ITSELF) has it!

Comment: "Is it a mandatory condition for HTTP client to send GET request immediately after initial connection?" No, but it's a really good idea, otherwise you are likely to run into server read timeouts, as you appear to be doing. These are not prohibited by the HTTP specification. I don't understand why you think you would want to do this. Not a real question.

Comment: No actually I am sniffing packets in between Web server and HTTP client, where sometimes(due to CPU load) we are holding packets for long time, then observed this issue first.

When observed the issue modified the HTTP client to replicate it.

Comment: When you observed what issue? And why did you modify the HTTP client to do something it shouldn't do?

Comment: Please refer my above comment :)

Answer (score 0):

Apache got a parameter called Timeout.

Its manual page ( [Apache Core - Timeout Directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#timeout) ) states:

> The TimeOut directive defines the length of time Apache will wait for I/O in various circumstances:
>
> 1. When reading data from the client, the length of time to wait for a 
>      TCP packet to arrive if the read buffer is empty.
> 2. When writing data to the client, the length of time to wait for an
>      acknowledgement of a packet if the send buffer is full.
> 3. In mod_cgi, the length of time to wait for output from a CGI script.
> 4. In mod_ext_filter, the length of time to wait for output from a
>      filtering process.
> 5. In mod_proxy, the default timeout value if ProxyTimeout is not
>      configured.

I think you fell into case **NUMBER ONE**

**EDIT**

I was lurking into W3 HTTP document and I found no refer to timeouts.

but into the chapter 8 (connections) I found:

[8.1.4 Practical Considerations](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec8.html#sec8)

*Servers will **usually** have some time-out value beyond which they will no longer maintain an inactive connection. (...) The use of persistent connections places no requirements on the length (or existence) of this time-out for either the client or the server.*

that sounds to me like "every server or client is free to choose his behaviour about inactive connection timeouts"

Comment: Thanks Davide for your answer, But my doubt is
"Is it a mandatory condition for HTTP client to send GET request immediately after initial connection."
Means not only Apache server but all HTTP server will follow this condition(When reading data from the client, the length of time to wait for a TCP packet to arrive if the read buffer is empty.)

Comment: Davide again thanks for your ans.
I will explain scenario once more:
We modified the curl/wget in such a way that 
these utilities will initiate a connection, but not sending the GET request to HTTP server(apache/lighthttpd) for some time(<1sec), but within this time period server is sending the FIN pkt.
While in normal TCP connection(Ex echo server) server is waiting for minutes(for timeouts as you mentioned) before sending FIN.
My doubt is, IS Server showing this behavior due to HTTP protocol.
Any points is helpful, thanks in advance :)

Comment: and my answer is: "depends on server, not by HTTP protocol itself"

Comment: But for normal TCP connection we are not observing FIN pkt, I gave you scenario also of TCP echo server, where we not observed FIN pkt, while with HTTP server we observed.

Comment: Would you mind to dump the two connection and post the pcap file?